# Looking for a latex directory class

Tags: directory

I'm lokking for a latex directory class. In order to print alphabetical directory of persons and enteprises. With rubrics for geographie, professionnal functions or enterprises, etc. Printing to A5 or A4 papers.

It will be fine also to create a password directory with Internet sites...

Do you know about such latex class ?

Thank you for your response.